# What does all capitalized Function name means in WinAPI?

Tags: windows, winapi, projfs

Informs the provider that a directory enumeration is starting

`

```
PRJ_START_DIRECTORY_ENUMERATION_CB PrjStartDirectoryEnumerationCb;

HRESULT PrjStartDirectoryEnumerationCb(
  const PRJ_CALLBACK_DATA *callbackData,
  const GUID *enumerationId
)
{...}
```

`
I am confused how to use this function.

Comment: The function's name is `PrjStartDirectoryEnumerationCb`, which isn't more capitalized that usual, is it? Anyhow, this seems to be a callback function, so it isn't a function in the Windows API, but a function you (or some other application developer) have written yourself. Here is the official documentation on the callback function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/projectedfslib/nc-projectedfslib-prj_start_directory_enumeration_cb

Comment: That means I can define a function with the same parameter but different name and it will work the same ?

Comment: Yes, you can name it whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at a callback (a generic programming concept, not specific to Win32), which is usually a reference to a function that you have to write yourself. In order to have the C/C++ compiler check that you've defined your callback function correctly, and to simplify usage of such callbacks, a `typedef` is often used. The Win32 API often uses all caps to define types of callbacks. In this case, `PRJ_START_DIRECTORY_ENUMERATION_CB` is the type of the function pointer (a pointer to the callback function that you have to write), and it is defined in `projectedfslib.h` as:

```
typedef
_Function_class_(PRJ_START_DIRECTORY_ENUMERATION_CB)
HRESULT
(CALLBACK PRJ_START_DIRECTORY_ENUMERATION_CB)(
    _In_ const PRJ_CALLBACK_DATA* callbackData,
    _In_ const GUID* enumerationId
    );
```

This definition has a lot of excess stuff in it that helps the Microsoft toolset validate various things related to the usage of this type of function pointer. When writing your own function that works for this type of callback, you don't necessarily have to repeat a lot of the things that are used in the `typedef`. The MSDN documentation for callbacks often shows an example of how you would write the method signature for your callback, and that example is usually simplified to strip off the excess stuff that the toolset needs, leaving the stuff the developer needs to define when writing their callback.

In this case, the example function is called `PrjStartDirectoryEnumerationCb`, but there is no function defined with that name. It's up to you to define a function that looks like what you see on MSDN. It doesn't have to have the same name -- you can name it whatever you like, and then you use your function's name anywhere the callback is needed.

```
HRESULT MyCallback(const PRJ_CALLBACK_DATA *callbackData, const GUID* enumerationId)
{
     // implement your callback here
}
```